# Easy way of Compute this limit

Tags: limits

Easy way to compute: $$\lim_{x\to \:0\:}\left(\left(\frac{a^x-x\cdot \ln\left(a\right)}{b^x-x\cdot \ln\left(b\right)}\right)^{\frac{1}{x^2}}\right)$$

Comment: are you sure that  the power is $\frac{1}{x^3}$, i guess it should be $\frac{1}{x^2}$

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Your right it is $1/x^2$, but I still don't know how to solve it, because I get a huge quotient rule and I am sure there is a simpler way

Comment: @EkaveeraKumarSharma Here is a picture: http://i.imgur.com/1ah84ls.png

Comment: @JamesSmith: Of course there is.. never every try L'Hopital's rule unless you do not even know the concrete expression for which you want a limit! Otherwise always use asymptotic expansions such as Taylor series. That is how computer algebra systems do it too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically as $x \to 0$  the function $$\left(\frac{a^x -x \, \ln a}{b^x -x \, \ln b}\right)^{1/x^2}$$ attains the form 1^infinity. As $\lim x \to a  [f(x)]^{g(x)}$ attains $1^{\infty}$ form we can modify limit as $e^{\lim x \to a (f(x)-1) g(x)}$

using the above rule, and after taking LCM your limit transforms to $e^{\lim x \to 0 (1/x^2){(a^x -x\ln a -b^x +x\ln b)/(b^x -x\ln b)}}$
  using expansion of $$a^x = 1 + (x\ln a)/1! + ((x\ln a)^2)/2! +.......$$
                     $$b^x = 1 +(x\ln b)/1!  + ((x\ln b)^2)/2! +....$$

your limit transforms to $$e^{\lim x-->0 (1/x^2){[((x\ln a)^2)/2!..... -((x\ln b)^2)/2!....]/(b^x -x\ln b)}}$$

cancel $x^2$ and then put $x \to 0$ you need not worry about other terms in Nr as they have positive powers of x and become 0

so finally u are left with $e^{{((\ln a)^2)-((\ln b)^2)}/2}$ which is the reqd limit

Answer (score 3):

Apply $\ln$ to get

$$\tag 1 \frac{\ln (a^x-x\ln a) - \ln (b^x-x\ln b)}{x^2}.$$

Using $e^u = 1 + u + u^2/2 +O(u^3)$ as $u\to 0,$ we get

$$a^x = e^{x\ln a} = 1 + x\ln a + (x\ln a)^2/2 + O(x^3).$$

A similar result holds for $b^x.$ Therefore $(1)$ equals

$$\tag 2 \frac{\ln (1+(x\ln a)^2/2 + O(x^3)) - \ln (1+(x\ln b)^2/2 + O(x^3))}{x^2}.$$

Now $\ln (1+u) = u + O(u^2).$ Therefore $(2)$ equals

$$\frac{(x\ln a)^2/2 -(x\ln b)^2/2 + O(x^3)}{x^2} \to (\ln a)^2/2 -(\ln b)^2/2 .$$

Exponentiating back gives $e^{(\ln a)^2/2 -(\ln b)^2/2}.$

Answer (score 2):

For any $a,b > 0$ and as $x \to 0$:
$\def\l{\!\left}$
$\def\r{\right}$

$a^x = \exp(x\ln(a)) \in 1 + x\ln(a) + \frac{1}{2}(x\ln(a))^2 + o(x^2)$.

$b^x = \exp(x\ln(b)) \in 1 + x\ln(b) + \frac{1}{2}(x\ln(b))^2 + o(x^2)$.

$\l( \dfrac{a^x - x\ln(a)}{b^x - x\ln(b)} \r)^\dfrac{1}{x^2} = \exp\l( \dfrac{1}{x^2}\ln\l( \dfrac{a^x - x\ln(a)}{b^x - x\ln(b)} \r) \r)$

$ \in \exp\l( \dfrac{1}{x^2}\ln\l( \dfrac{ 1 + \frac{1}{2}\ln(a)^2 x^2 + o(x^2) }{ 1 + \frac{1}{2}\ln(b)^2 x^2 + o(x^2) } \r) \r)$

$ \subseteq \exp\l( \dfrac{1}{x^2}\ln\l( 1 + \frac{1}{2}(\ln(a)^2-\ln(b)^2) x^2 + o(x^2) \r) \r)$

$ \subseteq \exp\l( \dfrac{1}{x^2} \l( \frac{1}{2}(\ln(a)^2-\ln(b)^2) x^2 + o(x^2) \r) \r)$

$ \subseteq \exp\l( \frac{1}{2}(\ln(a)^2-\ln(b)^2) + o(1) \r) = \exp\l( \frac{1}{2}(\ln(a)^2-\ln(b)^2) \r) ( 1 + o(1) )$

$ \to \exp\l( \frac{1}{2}(\ln(a)^2-\ln(b)^2) \r)$.

Comment: Note that this solution is purely mechanical. One may ask how to know how much of each asymptotic expansion to use. The answer is that it does not matter. If you cut off at some order and later find that the significant term cancels, then just go back and increase the order of expansion. This is what happens if we expand $a^x$ and $b^x$ to only first-order, so one the second try we expand to second order and it works. If you want more precise asymptotic behaviour, just expand to higher order.

Answer (score 0):

Let the desired limit be $L$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\log L &= \log\left(\lim_{x \to 0}\left(\frac{a^{x} - x\log a}{b^{x} - x\log b}\right)^{1/x^{2}}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\log\left(\frac{a^{x} - x\log a}{b^{x} - x\log b}\right)^{1/x^{2}}\text{ (via continuity of log)}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\log\left(\frac{a^{x} - x\log a}{b^{x} - x\log b}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\log\left(1 + \frac{a^{x} - x\log a}{b^{x} - x\log b} - 1\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\log\left(1 + \frac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{b^{x} - x\log b}\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{b^{x} - x\log b}\cdot\dfrac{\log\left(1 + \dfrac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{b^{x} - x\log b}\right)}{\dfrac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{b^{x} - x\log b}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{1}{x^{2}}\cdot\dfrac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{b^{x} - x\log b}\cdot 1\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - b^{x} - x(\log a - \log b)}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{a^{x} - 1 - x\log a}{x^{2}} - \frac{b^{x} - 1 - x\log b}{x^{2}}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to 0}(\log a)^{2}\cdot\frac{a^{x} - 1 - x\log a}{(x\log a)^{2}} - (\log b)^{2}\cdot\frac{b^{x} - 1 - x\log b}{(x\log b)^{2}}\notag\\
&= (\log a)^{2}\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^{u} - 1 - u}{u^{2}} - (\log b)^{2}\lim_{v \to 0}\frac{e^{v} - 1 - v}{v^{2}}\text{ (putting }u = x\log a, v = x\log b)\notag\\
&= \{(\log a)^{2} - (\log b)^{2}\}\lim_{u \to 0}\frac{e^{u} - 1 - u}{u^{2}}\notag
\end{align}
The last limit is easily seen to be $1/2$ either via one application of L'Hospital's Rule or through Taylor's series. Hence $$\log L = \frac{(\log a)^{2} - (\log b)^{2}}{2}$$ and therefore $$L = \exp\left(\frac{(\log a)^{2} - (\log b)^{2}}{2}\right)$$

Comment: Why the downvote??